# Xamarin.Forms StackLayout+ListView on Android - layout on top of each other

Tags: xamarin.forms

In this StackLayout content for ViewCell if I put FontSize="Large" attribute for first label it is rendered on top of label two. 
Looks like it's changed height is not taken into account when sizing whole ViewCell.

Problem exists on Android, layout works OK on Windows Phone Emulator, or when used without ListView.

```xml
<ListView x:Name="listView" BackgroundColor="Red">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <StackLayout>
          <Label Text="LABEL ONE" FontSize="Large" BackgroundColor="Green" />
          <Label Text="LABEL TWO" BackgroundColor="Yellow" />
        </StackLayout>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Am I missing something or is it a bug in layouting of Xamarin.Forms generated content?

Comment: I got confirmation from Xamarin that it is a bug existing in Forms 1.4.5.

Comment: try to use OnPlatform tag

Answer (score 0):

Try with this. You forgot the ViewCell.View mark.

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" BackgroundColor="Red">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
      <ViewCell.View>
        <StackLayout>
          <Label Text="LABEL ONE" FontSize="Large" BackgroundColor="Green" />
          <Label Text="LABEL TWO" BackgroundColor="Yellow" />
        </StackLayout>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```